# Is there any way to reduce the duration of Grievous Wounds?

Tags: league-of-legends

Are there any ways to reduce the duration of Grievous wounds while it is on you? Not necessarily get rid of it, but have it last for less time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, there is no way to remove or reduce the duration of Grievous Wounds in the current patch.

In previous patches, you could buy Quicksilver Sash. It's active effect removed all debuffs from your character, including GW. However, it now only removes CC (crowd control), or movement-impairing effects.

Also in previous patches, Soraka's ultimate, Wish, would remove GW before applying its healing effect. That was also removed, however.

Tenacity only affects some CC effects, and GW does not count as CC, so that does not reduce the duration either.

Comment: Slows, Roots (Snares), Stuns and Knockups (knockbacks) all count as CC, no need to differenciate movement impairing effects, since they fall under CC

Comment: @Oak Oh sorry, that was meant to be a clarification on the definition of crowd control, in case a reader is a new player or something.

Comment: And a random fun fact: Displacement effects (knockups and knockbacks/pulls) *can* be cleansed with QSS, but you are still effectively stunned until the animation completes. However, by cleansing the displacement, it allows you to flash away while the animation happens, which can occasionally save you.

Answer (score 0):

No, a tip to counter this effect is to use Shields whom are not affected by Grievous Wound.

Comment: I think this needs elaboration.  Are you saying that being hit by a GW attack doesn't inflict GW if it damages a shield, not HP?

Comment: @JMac he's saying shields are not reduced by GW, thus when someone is inflicted that status, instead of healing him, shield him.

Comment: @JMac The total amount absorbed by a shield is not affected by Grievious Wounds, so if the person is about to take damage then shielding them for an equivalent amount of health you would have healed them for (before GW) is going to leave them with a higher amount of health after the attack.  Obviously the real calculation tends not to be this ideal.

Comment: I mean:
If you're affected by Grievous Wound and you get a heal from an ally, you will receive a lower % of hp that you would receive if you're not affected by GW. This doesn't happen if you receive a shield, you will get the same amount of protection with or without GW, but you will be protected only from ad damage based on his % of lethality. If you want to be protected by ap damage, you need a magic shield, but even in this case it based on enemy magic penetration. Anyway there are a lot of things to be considered.